# Mobile: Back after edit should go to the edit again?

Tags: mobile, navigation, back-button, edit

**Scenario A:**

- Open app on the mobile and go to the list of homework;
- Click on create a new homework;
- Edit page is appearing;
- You fill up the form and click on "create homework";
- Redirects me to the homework page (not the list of homework);

  **Question:** *If I press back, should I go to the edit page OR the list of homework?*

**Scenario 2:**

- I'm on the list of homework page;
- I click on one homework;
- I go to the homework page (not the list of homework);
- I click edit homework;
- I go to the edit page;
- I update and click "update homework";
- Redirects me to the homework page (not the list of homework);

  **Question:** *If I press back should I go to the edit homework OR to the list of homework?*

This a web application, but will also run on a native app inside a web view, of course.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

For both the scenarios, pressing back should take the user to the **list of homework**.

The *Edit* action should only be accessible by the **Edit button**

When the user clicks on the **Back** button, he/she expects to go back a step in the workflow (which is the Homework list screen in your case) rather than going back to the previous screen.

Comment: Thanks. Is it possible to explain the reasoning behind this?

Comment: This is what the user expects. When I click on the **Back** button, I expect to go back a step in the workflow and not go back to the screen I came from. If I want to edit the homework again after saving it, then I would click on the Edit button

Comment: Ok, looks fair enough. Thanks again. I will see if there are other opinions, if not I will accept this answer.

Comment: The edit page isn't a page. It is a state of the homework page. As such it doesn't appear in the page history. Unless you leave the homework page while it is being edited, at which point what do you do? Require the user to dismiss the edit state when the user returns to either the create or homework page.